# Random forest in Caret running time

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, caret

I need to compare models performance on a dataset (binomial predictor and 170 variable, 4000 observation) and i'm unable to make the caret randomforest 'rf' model work.
My code is below and i've stopped it after 2 hours :

```
myfolds <- caret::createMultiFolds(milk_training_purged$pred, k = 10, times = 3) 
control <- caret::trainControl("repeatedcv", index = myfolds, selectionFunction = "oneSE")

model <- train(pred ~ ., data = milk_training_purged, 
          method = "rf", 
          metric = "Accuracy",
          preProc = c("nzv","center","scale"),
          tuneLength = 6,
          trControl = control)
```

If i understand it well caret is just a call function from the randomForest pckg and therefore i tried running my dataset with it.

```
model <- randomForest(pred ~ ., data=milk_training_purged, proximity=TRUE)
```

and it only takes 1 minutes to create the model.
I know that it doesn't do the cross-validation that is done with caret but it should'nt take so long.

I would like to simply rewrite the RandomForest code into Caret::train.
Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for the silly question

Comment: could you attach your data using dput()?

Comment: Try the `ranger` package which also has a `caret` interface; it's a faster version of random forests.